# How to get to Dashboard

Tags: piranha-cms

(I Am just getting started with Parahna CMS. It seems like exactly what I need, but I am having trouble getting started).

I walked through the steps in the Getting Started post, and now have an MVC 5 project, with Parahna CMS installed through Nuget.

I updated the config so it connects to the database, and it connected and updated the database.

So now I fire up the app and it goes to the home page.  There is no link anywhere to log in, so by trial and error, I find I can log in by going to /Manager.  However, after logging in, it just shows me the login page again.

How do I get to the dashboard page to manage users, pages etc?

Greg

Comment: Well, I tried creating a new project from scratch, this time choosing the non-MVC version and that is working fine for me.  After logging in, it takes me to the Dashboard as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the MVC template you used set up the authentication in a way the didn't work together with the manager interface! Because of this you were never able to log in!

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Thanks @Hakan, I appreciate the response!