# PirahnaCMS Manager using Organizational Authentication in project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, piranha-cms

While using Windows Organizational authentication in the ASP.net MVC project, I am unable to access the /Manager portion of PirahnaCMS. Whenever I attempt to login, it just redirects back to the login page. Is there a solution to this problem, or a workaround?

Someone asked this question, but no one posted a solution: [How to get to Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275884/how-to-get-to-dashboard/22283151#22283151)

Best Regards,
Saad

Comment: The link you posted has an accepted answer.  Have you tried working with what was posted in that answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Piranha CMS manager uses **forms authentication**. If you've configured another form of authentication in your main web.config the manager login won't work. In the upcoming version (2.3.0) the authentication mechanism will be replaceable, but in the current version the manager needs forms authentication.

You have two possible solutions:

1) Try configure the manager area to use Forms authentication by adding a separate web.config to this area.

2) Set the "front-application" to run in passive mode, i.e. disable the manager. Add a different web without the front-end and just the manager pointing to the same database.

Regards

Håkan

Comment: In your example #2, if you set up a different site to handle the CMS Management part, how would you handle the media content coming from the CMS site. IE if you had CMS.site.com as your CMS only site, and www.site.com as your actual site, how would you get the content to load if you are using the CMS on an existing site?

Comment: You'd have to replace the default mediaprovider with something that stores the files in a central location, like the Azure provider that uses blog-storage. It's a fairly simple API to implement and it would be easy to create a provider which stores the media files in the database!